# Does setting the cursor for Kendo UI Chart series via css work?

Tags: css, svg, kendo-ui

I've currently got a CSS rule for a KendoUI Chart (that is defined in a razor view):

```
/* use :not(:last-child) to ignore legend */
#idOfMyChart g:not(:last-child) path
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This sets the cursor rule for the right svg elements in the chart. However, hovering over the series seems to redraw the chart (to display the tooltip) and stops the cursor from displaying as per the css rule.

Is there a way to get these svg elements to display the cursor as a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nohinn on the [Kendo forum](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/dataviz/chart/how-can-i-get-css-cursor-to-work-for-chart-series.aspx).

The correct selector to use for the chart series is `path[data-model-id]`:

```
/* use presence of [data-model-id] attribute to select series in chart */
#idOfMyChart path[data-model-id]
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following resolve the problem to get the pointer cursor for all series in donut kendo graph.
Create the following css style in the page where is the control.

```
  #Graphdonut > svg > g > g {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

where Grapdonut is the name of your chart

Because this a is hack in code can change in other version of kendo, that was tested in kendo 2014

I hope that this help you.

Comment: Direct descent selectors are problematic with older versions of IE. If the markup structure changes, this will break, the path[] selector above works fine and seems more robust.

Comment: Works fine in kendo Pie-chart. Great.